# Converting rsync --stats output to GB?

Tags: bash, rsync

When using `--stats` with rsync, you get a report at the bottom of the transfer log.

```
Number of files: 211009
Number of files transferred: 410
Total file size: 903119614118 bytes
Total transferred file size: 9046197739 bytes
Literal data: 0 bytes
Matched data: 0 bytes
File list size: 5864077
File list generation time: 23.204 seconds
File list transfer time: 0.000 seconds
Total bytes sent: 5865513
Total bytes received: 1441
```

I would like to convert `Total file size` and `Total transferred file size` in place to GB, so it becomes

```
Number of files: 211009
Number of files transferred: 410
Total file size: 903 GB
Total transferred file size: 9 GB
Literal data: 0 bytes
Matched data: 0 bytes
File list size: 5864077
File list generation time: 23.204 seconds
File list transfer time: 0.000 seconds
Total bytes sent: 5865513
Total bytes received: 1441
```

**Question**

How should that be done?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`rsync --stats -h /your /paths --and --options`

`-h` stands for human readable.

i.e :

```
$ man rsync | grep -A5 human-readable.format.
              Output  numbers in a more human-readable format.  This makes big
              numbers output using larger units, with a K, M, or G suffix.  If
              this  option  was  specified  once,  these units are K (1000), M
              (1000*1000), and G (1000*1000*1000); if the option is  repeated,
              the units are powers of 1024 instead of 1000.
```

And if you add another `-h`, you will have GiB instead of GB.

Comment: It is a very interesting solution, but I see now, that I hadn't written that it had to be in place. Please see updated OP.